# Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer.AdomdException in BIDS

Tags: ssas, bids

We are using following MDX to create dynamic named set to generate future dates for one of our cube -

```
LASTPERIODS(100, STRTOMEMBER("[Calenar].[Calendar Date].&[" + 
CSTR(FORMAT(DATEADD("D",100,[Forecast].[Date Recorded].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE),
    "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00")) + 
"]"))
```

Above query expression executes successfully in MDX Query Analyzer. But after cube is processed successfully, we are facing issue while browsing the cube and getting following error:

- Error occurred retrieving name set: Execution of the managed stored
  procedure DATEADD failed with following error
  'Microsoft::AnalysisServices::AdomdServer::AdomdException
- Internal Error : An external component returned an error (HRESULT = ).
- The following system error occurred: Type Mismatch

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Referenced Link - [MDX Named Set Rolling Date Range](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/1718/mdx-named-set-rolling-date-range)

Thanks,

Kinjal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any null or "non-date" values in the [Forecast].[Date Recorded] members? Does this work when you run it as an MDX query on your cube?

Comment: We have non-date values in members of [Forecast].[Date Recorded] dimension but we convert them to valid date formats.

Comment: @Kinjal what is the data type of [Forecast].[Date Recorded].CURRENTMEMBER, I wonder if you are having a d/m/y m/d/y issue with datetimes? That could work in QA but not connection, due to different default language?